# (VB.NET) Find all duplicates in a list of objects based on multiple properties

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of CommissionStatement objects which i created. I need to create a new list which only holds the duplicates found in this list based on 3 properties: Firm; Provider; and Total (ie each of these 3 have to be the same in 2 or more objects for it to be recognized as a duplicate)

Object is a simple object of strings at the moment.

```
Private Class CommissionStatement
    Property Provider As String
    Property Firm As String
    Property Source As String
    Property Media As String
    Property Total As String
    Property Received As String
End Class
```

I have a list of all CommissionStatments as follows:

```
Dim fileLocation As String = importText.Text
        Dim csvText As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(fileLocation).Replace(", ", " ") 
        Dim providerString As String = ""
        Dim allStatements = New List(Of CommissionStatement)
        Dim countIndex As Integer = 0, maxIndex As Integer = csvText.Split(vbLf).Length
        For Each line As String In csvText.Split(vbLf)
            '' Remove the top row
            countIndex += 1
            If countIndex = 1 Then
                Continue For
            End If
            statementProgress.Value = ((countIndex / maxIndex) * 100)
            '' Build the New commissionStatement object and add it to the allStatements list
            If Not line = "" Then
                Dim commissionStatement = New CommissionStatement
                With commissionStatement
                    .Provider = line.Split(",")(0)
                    .Firm = line.Split(",")(1)
                    .Source = line.Split(",")(2)
                    .Media = line.Split(",")(3)
                    .Total = line.Split(",")(4)
                End With
                providerString &= commissionStatement.Provider & ","
                allStatements.Add(commissionStatement)
            End If
        Next
```

First post on StackOverflow so sorry if its not very clear! The duplicate list needs to also be a list of CommissionStatements which contain the duplicates from the allStatements list based on Firm Provider and Total

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a lambda expression. The function below should do what you ask.

```
Private Function GetDuplicateCommisionStatements(tempStatement As CommissionStatement) As List(Of CommissionStatement)
    Return allStatements.FindAll(Function(x) x.Firm = tempStatement.Firm And x.Provider = tempStatement.Provider And x.Total = tempStatement.Total)
End Function
```

And use it like this..

```
duplicatelist = GetDuplicateCommisionStatements(testCommisionStatement)
```

using your own object names of course.

Incidentally, you could shorten the sub using the `With` statement like below

```
Private Function GetDuplicateCommisionStatements(tempStatement As CommissionStatement) As List(Of CommissionStatement)
    With tempStatement
        Return allStatements.FindAll(Function(x) x.Firm = .Firm And x.Provider = .Provider And x.Total = .Total)
    End With
End Function
```